# Swiftmailer, Gmail, Cloud9 not working

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, cloud9-ide

So, I'm about 2 weeks into trying to learn PHP and I'm working on cloud9, which doesn't support the mail() function. After a lot of looking around on here I thought I'd try Swiftmailer and Gmail. For some reason, I can't seem to get this right even after literally copying formats. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but I can't even get echo statements to print after the first line. I've looked at numerous previous posts. I know this is probably a really dumb problem, but I could really use some help. Any alternatives that would work better for me in cloud9 would also be appreciated if this isn't a possibility. Thank you so much for your time.

```
  <?php
        require_once '/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
       $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
            ->setUsername(USERNAME)
            ->setPassword(PASSWORD);
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('This is a subject')
            ->setFrom(array('toemail@domain.com' => 'My Name'))
            ->setTo(array('fromemail@domain.com' => 'Some Name'))
            ->setBody('Hello world!');
        $request = $mailer->send($message);
        echo "Hello!";
    ?>
```

If I put an echo before $request, it still doesn't echo. Also, I am getting all this in my terminal:

> > Started apache2 [Tue Mar 24 18:39:11.139091 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12191] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
> >     PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations [Tue Mar
> >     24 18:39:11.139160 2015] [core:notice] [pid 12191] AH00094: Command
> >     line: 'apache2'
>
> ==> /home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/log/access.log <==
>   10.240.52.53 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4997 "https://ide.c9.io/hrguyll/seproject" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.73.244 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:21 +0000] "GET /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 500 205
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.169.157 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4997 "https://ide.c9.io/hrguyll/seproject" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.52.53 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:29 +0000] "GET /main_login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2589
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.215.225 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:42 +0000] "GET /testmail.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2277
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.169.157 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:44 +0000] "POST /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 500 205 "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/testmail.php"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.73.244 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:39:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4997 "https://ide.c9.io/hrguyll/seproject" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.215.225 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:40:01 +0000] "GET /testmail.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2277
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.73.244 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:40:04 +0000] "POST /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 500 205 "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/testmail.php"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.169.157 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:40:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4997 "https://ide.c9.io/hrguyll/seproject" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.169.157 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:40:15 +0000] "GET /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 500 205
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.73.244 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:40:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4997 "https://ide.c9.io/hrguyll/seproject" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.169.157 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:40:41 +0000] "GET /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 500 205
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.169.157 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:41:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4997 "https://ide.c9.io/hrguyll/seproject" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
>   10.240.215.225 - - [24/Mar/2015:18:41:30 +0000] "GET /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 500 205
>   "https://seproject-hrguyll.c9.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"

Comment: If you put an echo statement right before the line with `$request`, does it hit that? Is there any output/feedback in the terminal?

Comment: Hmm, can't tell a ton from the terminal output. Your `swift_required.php` is definitely in the folder you are referencing?

Comment: @BradyDowling , Yeah I believe so. I mean, it's cloud9 so I'm not 100% sure if there is anything I'm missing in the address (I'm sure It's likely) but I have checked in the navigation tab and it appears to be the right spot. I hope that's all the problem is, but it's just trying to figure that out :|

Comment: The log you pasted is just the access log, and not the error log. Can you check the error log. It should be in ~/lib/apache2/log/error.log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but just in case:
https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/discuss/5582e67bea39a939002242a3
As stated in the link below, Cloud9 is hosted by Google Cloud Engine, which does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. There is a workaround using SendGrid but I haven't tried.